# Display comments in textview/accept comments in editview to use in quiz app

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Working on a simple android quiz app. I'd like to ask the user questions about comments made in the xml and java files. How can I write xml comments in the strings.xml file,   to appear on the screen?

```
<string name="comments_1"> // </string>
<string name="comments_2"> <!-- --></string>
<string name="comments_3"> /**  */</string>


<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/comments_2"/>
```

Comment: Is the App fetching the questions from the internet or not ?

Comment: Not at the moment, this app is just an extra resource for me. That I want to continue building as I continue learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape it like so:

```
<string name="comments_2">&lt;!-- --&gt;</string>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I figured out 
    &lt; means less than
    &gt; means greater than